# How to apply oneway change to two dropdowns using same array [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to `Angular`. Sorry for not able to frame the question very well. I'm making a sales comparison component in angular. I've two dropdown lists inside a widget. One Primary and the other one being secondary. My task is to sync these two dropdown lists. What I mean is, If I select an option in primary, that option should get selected in secondary also. But the reverse should not happen. This is what I meant by `oneway change` in my question.

Here's a screenshot to explain further:
[image]

that means the reverse selection shouldn't happen.
For saving everyone's time I've created an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ing1t9). You can directly look into that also.

And here's my code:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<div class="time-selector">
    <p-overlayPanel class="my-overlay" #op>
        <br />
        <div class="inner-panel">
          <h2>Time selection widget</h2>
          <br>
          <h3>Primary dropdown</h3>
          <select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" name="source">
            <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
              {{ mode }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <br><br><br><br>
          <h3>Secondary dropdown</h3>
          <select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" name="source">
            <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
              Previous {{ mode }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </p-overlayPanel>
</div>

<div class="input-field" (click)="op.toggle($event)" style="margin-left: 100px">
    <h4 style="color: white; float: left; margin-left: 10px;">Click here</h4>
</div>
```

Note: Secondary dropdown is also using the same array but the values are prefixed with *Previous*.

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-timeselector',
    templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timeselector.component.css']
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {
    modes = ['Year', 'Quarter', 'Sprint'];
    public selectedSource = 'Year';
}
```

Please correct me and help me implement that logic.
And please let me know whether it is even doable or not. Maybe I'm wasting mine and everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[(ngModel)]` should be different on both the dropdown. For the primary dropdown change, you can set the value for the secondary using `(ngModelChange)`

Try like this:

```
<h3>Primary dropdown</h3>

<select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" name="source" (ngModelChange)="secondaryMode = primaryMode">
     <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          {{ mode }}
     </option>
</select>

<br><br><br><br>

<h3>Secondary dropdown</h3>

<select [(ngModel)]="secondaryMode" name="source">
     <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          Previous {{ mode }}
     </option>
</select>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ubvfu?embed=1&file=src/app/timeselector/timeselector.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-timeselector',
    templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timeselector.component.css']
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {

    modes = ['Year', 'Quarter', 'Sprint'];

    public selectedSource = 'Year';
    private selectedDestination = this.selectedSource;
}
```

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<div class="time-selector">
    <p-overlayPanel class="my-overlay" #op>
        <br />
        <div class="inner-panel">
          <h2>Time selection widget</h2>
          <br>
          <h3>Primary dropdown</h3>
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedSource" (ngModelChange)="selectedDestination=$event"> name="source">
            <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
              {{ mode }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <br><br><br><br>
          <h3>Secondary dropdown</h3>
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedDestination" name="source">
            <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
              Previous {{ mode }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </p-overlayPanel>
</div>

<div class="input-field" (click)="op.toggle($event)" style="margin-left: 100px">
    <h4 style="color: white; float: left; margin-left: 10px;">Click here</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the same variable for ngModel, when you update one form component, it will change all others using the same model.

If it was me, I would use angular reactive forms (if your app is a large form like you suggest, it will make managing it much easier):

```
modes = ['Year', 'Quarter', 'Sprint'];
myForm = new FormGroup({
        controlA: new FormControl(null),
        controlB: new FormControl(null)
        )}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.get("controlA").valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
       this.myForm.get(['controlB']).setValue(x);
     })
}

<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="myForm">
<label>ControlA</label>
<select class="form-control"
        formControlName="controlA">
<option disabled selected value> --Select-- </option>
<option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [ngValue]="mode" >{{mode}}</option>
</select>


<label>ControlB</label>
<select class="form-control"
        formControlName="controlB">
<option disabled selected value> --Select-- </option>
<option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [ngValue]="mode" >{{mode}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-zngaz4)

Comment: There's a lot more circus going on with the actual project. :-) :-). I'll try this solution and will get back to you asap. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It is not making any changes to the secondary dropdown list.

Comment: Added a working solution with a stackblitz explanation.

Comment: I would strong recommend using the form Library over ngModel, it gives you much greater flexibility. I would only recommend the use of ngModel if you have one input that does not need validating.